# Set up network interface for automatic connection

Tags: ethernet

I have an ethernet device P2P connected to the NIC in my system.
When the remote device is rebooted or changes its IP address, the local network interface goes down and loses its IP address.
How can I make the local interface automatically reconnect in such cases and remember its IP?

I know how to set an interface up programmatically and set an IP, but I don't want to check in a loop, there should be a better way.

Comment: Why aren't you using Zeroconf for this?

Comment: What system is this on? At least on Linux, this doesn't occur. Surprising it would on *any* Unix-variant. Unless you've got NetworkManager doing it.

Comment: This is Ubuntu.  Could you please point, what is "clean" behaviour, without NetworkManager: to keep connection and settings in such a case or to loose them  like in my situation?